# In angular Pushing objects in array getting duplicated

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

EventEmitter in service

```
toshoppinglist = new EventEmitter<Ingredients[]>()
```

Emitting method

```
toshoppinglist() {
    this.slservice.toshoppinglist.emit(this.item.ingredients);
  }
```

```
ingredients : Ingredient []
```

Subscribing to emit and pushing emitted values

```
this.slservice.toshoppinglist.subscribe(
        (ingredients: Ingredients[]) => {
          for (let item of ingredients) {
            this.ingredients.push(item);
          }
        }

      )
```

Now, when pushing new values into the array,it's getting duplicated.It's work fine for first pushing,but getting duplicated after that.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz of this problem?

Comment: I am very new in developing. But I am going to try.

Comment: You can reset like this `ingredients : Ingredient [] = []` before for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first in my opinion you use wrongly EventEmitter. Eventemitters used only inside DUMB components to raise an event to Smart component. And not inside services. Second, yes it will be duplicated. Imagine you have button which will raise this eventemitter and we emit the same ingredient every time. Inside the subscribe you didnt check that new ingredient are different. And because you use list, it doesnt care if you have duplicates. So a solution is to add to the subscribe a check that it will push only - new- ingredients.

Comment: But how can a button raises event if i clicked it once? Can you give me a hints how can i check for duplicate items ?

Comment: Mmm.. please read https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs and there the section about Output. I'm not 100% understand your question, because button can raise event if it clicked once. Also, you emit a list, so of course it will be hard to determine what is new. In my opinion, refactor it so every emit will be for a single ingredient, and then you just need to search if this single ingredient already in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to add a check in your subscription function.

currentIngredients: Ingredients[];

this.slservice.toshoppinglist.subscribe(
        (ingredients: Ingredients[]) => {
     
>    //here you need the if condition comparing it to a current
> ingredients array to see if it exists or not
  
   for(let item of ingredients) {
   if(this.currentIngredients.includes(item) {
// in this case you should increment the count of ingredient
   currentIngredients[item].count++; 
    }
  else {
 // this should only add non-existing items ingredients list
  this.currentIngredients.push(item)
}
}
```

}

Comment: I get your solution but the problem is if I want to push same element twice,then it will not work.Actually what happens when I push first element it pushed correctly,then on every push it pushed the element twice or thrice times .

Comment: It will.  If you mean ingredient item by element, it will simply push and assign a count property to it if ingredient already exists. If it doesn't exist it will push a new ingredient in outer array.  What exactly do you want to accomplish? Say you are adding    ['cheese', 'ham'] first time. Say you do the same second time, do you want to keep only distinct ingredients and count attached?

Comment: No I want to keep both of the same elements. And how are you accessing currentingredients by item ,is count a function to count how many items in array ?Sorry for my little knowledge ?

Comment: I thought you can just add a count property to Ingredient type to store how many of each ingredient you need. You are receiving data in your subscribe method as (ingredients: Ingredients[]). You can easily iterate over the ingredient with for of or for in loops.